# How to have a nested DTO?

Tags: entity-framework, serialization, entity-framework-6, dto

I have this as my entity object:

```
    public partial class RFID_Zones
    {
        public RFID_Zones()
        {
            this.RFID_ZonePoints = new HashSet<RFID_ZonePoints>();
        }

        public int PK_ZoneId { get; set; }
        public int PK_FK_ShipId { get; set; }
        public string ZoneName { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }

        public virtual Ship Ship { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<RFID_ZonePoints> RFID_ZonePoints { get; set;}
}
```

I am trying to pull all these with this code:

```
result = _db.RFID_Zones.Where(x => x.PK_FK_ShipId == shipId).Include(x => x.RFID_ZonePoints).ToList();
```

This works, but I cannot serialize it without getting a circular reference error. Upon Googling I find I should use a Data Transfer Object so I have this:

```
public class ZoneDto
{
    public ZoneDto()
    {
        this.Zones = new List<RFID_ZonePoints>();
    }
    public int PK_ZoneId { get; set; }
    public int PK_FK_ShipId { get; set; }
    public string ZoneName { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public List<RFID_ZonePoints> Zones { get; set; }
}
```

And:

```
var dto = zones.Select(x => new ZoneDto { PK_ZoneId = x.PK_ZoneId, PK_FK_ShipId = x.PK_FK_ShipId,
                        Color = x.Color, ZoneName = x.ZoneName, Zones = x.RFID_ZonePoints.ToList()});
```

I still have the issue of the RFID_ZonePoints list. It's a list of a different entity. How can I get those into a data transfer object as well?

Comment: `Select()` to project them as well, or use AutoMapper.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks. I don't know why I didn't think to do that, haha.